# Error trying to upload a profile picture

Tags: php, upload, warnings

Im creating a website and i have some error trying to upload profile pictures...
This is the code:

HTML

```
<div id="upload_container" class="user_container profile">
<div class="container"><a class="btn cerrar"><span class="icon close"></span></a></div>
<div class="formulario">
<form action="include/php/upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<h1>Selecciona una imagen</h1>
<input type="file" id="profileImage" name="profileImage" required />
<input type="submit" id="boton_perfil" value="Subir" class="btn" />
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

PHP

```
    <?php
    if($_FILES['profileImage']['name']){
    $mensaje = "";
    if(!$_FILES['profileImage']['error']){
        $imagen = rename($_FILES['profileImage']['tmp_name'], "user");
        $dimensiones = getimagesize(rtrim($_FILES['profileImage']['tmp_name']));
        $width = $dimensiones[0];
        $height = $dimensiones[1];

        if($_FILES['profileImage']['type'] != 'image/jpg'){
            $mensaje = "<div id='error_alert'><div class='error_container'><i class='fa fa-times awesome error_close btn'></i><div class='error_text'>El archivo debe tener extension .jpg</div></div></div>";
        }

        else if($width != 540 || $height != 540){
            $mensaje = "<div id='error_alert'><div class='error_container'><i class='fa fa-times awesome error_close btn'></i><div class='error_text'>El archivo debe ser 540x540</div></div></div>";
        }

        else if($_FILES['profileImage']['size'] > (1024000)){
            $valid_file = false;
            $mensaje = "<div id='error_alert'><div class='error_container'><i class='fa fa-times awesome error_close btn'></i><div class='error_text'>La imagen pesa demasiado</div></div></div>";
        }

        else if($valid_file){
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profileImage']['tmp_name'], "../database/usuarios/".$_POST["usuario"]."/".$imagen);
            $mensaje = "<div id='error_alert'><div class='error_container'><i class='fa fa-times awesome error_close btn'></i><div class='error_text'>Tu imagen ha sido actualizada</div></div></div>";
        }
    } else {
        $message = "<div id='error_alert'><div class='error_container'><i class='fa fa-times awesome error_close btn'></i><div class='error_text'>Hubo un error".$_FILES['photo']['error']."</div></div></div>";
    }
}
?>
```

This is the error [LINK](https://gyazo.com/e6fa5c13369f900031afad8647124b2d)

When a user registers in the web, a default picture is set.
The idea is to take a picture, change the name like the default picture and move it where the default one was... making some exceptions before, like size, dimensions, etc.

**UPDATED**

Warning: getimagesize(C:\wamp\tmp\phpF4F3.tmp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\tapeHD\include\php\upload.php on line 6

Comment: Can you include the error in the question so it's easier to see?

Comment: As a side remark, it is a bad practice to store user-uploaded files inside the webroot. I can't tell if it's relevant here, but wanted to raise awareness on this.

Comment: **You should not change the question once it has been answered**, as once you change it, it makes any answer already posted irrelevant and nonsence. As I said you should ask a **new question** so any answers offered are relevant to the question.

Comment: Ok sorry. I'm new in the forum.

Comment: I have rolled your changes back on this question. I will look for the new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have renamed the temporary upload file and then tried to use the old name

```
 $imagen = rename($_FILES['profileImage']['tmp_name'], "user");

 $dimensiones = getimagesize(rtrim($_FILES['profileImage']['tmp_name']));
```

Later in your code you then do

```
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['profileImage']['tmp_name'], 
                    "../database/usuarios/".$_POST["usuario"]."/".$imagen);
```

This will also fail due to the file not being there.

Also `$imagen` created by the `rename()` is a boolean `true or false` and not a filename.

You dont need to do the rename on the temporary file. You can pick any name for the file when you do the `move_uploaded_file()`

Comment: OK, I did it, and warnings dont appear... But It doesnt still work. I have changed the code and when I upload a photo, nothing happens. Even errors dont appear :S

Comment: OK, you had better ask another question. Post the code as it is now after your changes, so we can look for the new problem.

Comment: Done, some help would be nice. Thanks too much